# How to register custom culture in Azure?

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, azure, culture

We have an application(built with Angular + ASP.Net Web API) in which I have to support cultures for USA,UK,New Zealand,South African,Papua New Guinea(PNG),Fiji etc.But I just realized that Microsoft does not have any built-in support for cultures for countries like PNG,Fiji etc.So,I built a custom culture(For example,"x-en-PG" for PNG) to support these countries as per the MSDN documentation(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469(v=vs.90).aspx).

My application is hosted in Azure environment.

I was able to register it successfully on my development machine since I am running it with admin rights.But I am not sure how to register a custom culture in Azure!!! Please help..

I also checked this MSDN documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404375(v=vs.100).aspx) and I believe it is not going to help in Azure.

Is there any alternative ways to build and register a culture which supports Azure environment too?

Here is the code to register custom culture:

```
var customCultureRegionBuilder = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder("x-en-PG",
                        CultureAndRegionModifiers.None);
                    var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-AU");
                    customCultureRegionBuilder.LoadDataFromCultureInfo(cultureInfo);

                    var regionInfo = new RegionInfo("AU");
                    customCultureRegionBuilder.LoadDataFromRegionInfo(regionInfo);

                    //Set values sepcific to PNG culture
                    customCultureRegionBuilder.Parent = cultureInfo;
                    customCultureRegionBuilder.RegionEnglishName = "Papua New Guinea (PNG)";
                    customCultureRegionBuilder.RegionNativeName = "Papua New Guinea (PNG)";
                    customCultureRegionBuilder.CultureEnglishName = "English (PNG)";
                    customCultureRegionBuilder.CultureNativeName = "English (PNG)";
                    customCultureRegionBuilder.CurrencyEnglishName = "Papua New Guinean Kina";
                    customCultureRegionBuilder.CurrencyNativeName = "Papua New Guinean Kina";
                    customCultureRegionBuilder.ISOCurrencySymbol = "PGK";
                    customCultureRegionBuilder.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "K";
                    customCultureRegionBuilder.TwoLetterISORegionName = "PG";
                    customCultureRegionBuilder.ThreeLetterISORegionName = "PNG";
                    customCultureRegionBuilder.ThreeLetterWindowsRegionName = "PNG";
                    customCultureRegionBuilder.TwoLetterISOLanguageName = "en";
                    customCultureRegionBuilder.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName = "eng";
                    customCultureRegionBuilder.Register();
```

Comment: As an alternative, and if your culture is only used inside your application (and not any other processes), how about just constructing the `CultureInfo` instances on application startup and storing them in static state?

Comment: @Dai Thanks for your response. I think to create     CultureInfo instances,we need to pass the culture("x-en-PG") to the constructor of     CultureInfo. Since in my case,there is no culture called "x-en-PG" until I register it.So,the constructor initialization fails.

Comment: Please post your code that you currently use to create new cultures.

Comment: @Dai I have updated my question with the code snippet

Comment: have you figured this out?  Looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14955959/register-custom-culture-in-windows-azure has the same question

Comment: @Phil Sadly that's for the older Cloud Services, which gave you more control (as you were effectively deploying VMs, so could run what you wanted on them).